# How to "run" an exported Android app using Eclipse + Proguard?

Tags: android, eclipse, proguard

I can debug/run my Android app via Eclipse and I can export out an obfuscated/shrinked .APK.

However, in order to test the my "Release/Exported" .APK builds, I'm having to **manually** copy them to my phone (after enabling Disk mode) and install them from there (after disabling Disk mode).

As you can see, it's quite a faff! **:o(**

Is there not a quick way of "running" a release build after you've exported it via Eclipse?

Thanks!

Comment: This is the way I've always done it. Only takes about 1 minute. It shouldn't be much faffing about as you should have ironed out all the bugs and got it working in the debug version first. :)

Comment: So basically you just want to put the .apk file  on the phone and then run it?

Comment: Also, you do know if you connect via USB and are developing your app you can upload it straight to the phone? (Providing you have the ADB driver)

Comment: Cheers for the advice. The faff I refer to is switching phone to/from disk mode.  I completely agree, there should be little repetition as that's what "Debugging" is for, but I recently ran into a few issues with ProGuard  breaking my code due to over-obfuscation (sorted now - after tweaking .cfg).  I always have the phone connected while debugging (tend to debug on phone), but wondered if there's an ADB/other command I can run from my PC/Eclipse to automate the installation of the exported .APK file?

Comment: If you use Ant to create the release (signed and obfuscated) version, then you can install it via the USB with the "ant installr" command. (You can also get it to sign and export automatically when you build if you set up the keystore and passwords in the ant.properties file.)

Comment: Just realised that the answer is probably very simple...
http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#move
... but use the path to the exported/release .APK instead of the debug build.

Comment: @PaulNicholas adb install [-r] <path_to_apk> did the trick. I came here also looking for a less-"faff" way of doing it. Great.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose easiest way is too, what i do generally for my projects, is creating batch files to compile project, but here in eclipse we have easy way by simply exporting project. and once .apk is ready we can connect device and run batch file with following cmnd :

install_to_device.bat :

```
cd  YOUR_Android_PATH\platform-tools\
adb install [-r] [exported_apk_path]
```